# Unity Ads re-direct to previous Activity on onUnityAdsFinish()

Tags: android, unityads

I was stuck for 2days to find out the error code inside my app.
I am implemented Unity Ads into android studio project and it was successful showing ads but after ads closed it go back to the previous activity, Example below:

1. MainActivity
2. Level Selection Activity
3. Game Play Activity (Game Lose then showing ads) after successful showing ads and then we close the ads, it's not stay at the Game Play Activity but it's re-direct to Level Selection Activity.

Anyone face that issue like me before? and how to solve this?

Note: I do nothing at onUnityAdsFinish()

Best Regards,
Virak

Comment: The same situation here. This bug is driving me crazy